# google-api-python-client broken by OAuth2?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-bigquery, pycrypto, google-api-python-client

I am trying to check whether a certain dataset exists in BigQuery and I get this very strange error I've never had untill yesterday:

```
ERROR:dsUtils.bq_utils:Could not check if dataset tmp exists.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\paco\Anaconda3\envs\visitForecastEnv\lib\site-packages\dsUtils\bq_utils.py", line 113, in _get
    resp = bq_service.datasets().get(projectId=self.project_id, datasetId=self.id).execute(num_retries=2)
  File "C:\Users\paco\Anaconda3\envs\visitForecastEnv\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\util.py", line 137, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\paco\Anaconda3\envs\visitForecastEnv\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 755, in execute
    method=str(self.method), body=self.body, headers=self.headers)
  File "C:\Users\paco\Anaconda3\envs\visitForecastEnv\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 93, in _retry_request
    resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\paco\Anaconda3\envs\visitForecastEnv\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 598, in new_request
    self._refresh(request_orig)
  File "C:\Users\paco\Anaconda3\envs\visitForecastEnv\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 864, in _refresh
    self._do_refresh_request(http_request)
  File "C:\Users\paco\Anaconda3\envs\visitForecastEnv\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 891, in _do_refresh_request
    body = self._generate_refresh_request_body()
  File "C:\Users\paco\Anaconda3\envs\visitForecastEnv\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 1597, in _generate_refresh_request_body
    assertion = self._generate_assertion()
  File "C:\Users\paco\Anaconda3\envs\visitForecastEnv\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\service_account.py", line 318, in _generate_assertion
    key_id=self._private_key_id)
  File "C:\Users\paco\Anaconda3\envs\visitForecastEnv\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\crypt.py", line 97, in make_signed_jwt
    signature = signer.sign(signing_input)
  File "C:\Users\paco\Anaconda3\envs\visitForecastEnv\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\_pycrypto_crypt.py", line 101, in sign
    return PKCS1_v1_5.new(self._key).sign(SHA256.new(message))
  File "C:\Users\paco\Anaconda3\envs\visitForecastEnv\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_v1_5.py", line 112, in sign
    m = self._key.decrypt(em)
  File "C:\Users\paco\Anaconda3\envs\visitForecastEnv\lib\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py", line 174, in decrypt
    return pubkey.pubkey.decrypt(self, ciphertext)
  File "C:\Users\paco\Anaconda3\envs\visitForecastEnv\lib\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey\pubkey.py", line 93, in decrypt
    plaintext=self._decrypt(ciphertext)
  File "C:\Users\paco\Anaconda3\envs\visitForecastEnv\lib\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py", line 235, in _decrypt
    r = getRandomRange(1, self.key.n-1, randfunc=self._randfunc)
  File "C:\Users\paco\Anaconda3\envs\visitForecastEnv\lib\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py", line 126, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("%s object has no %r attribute" % (self.__class__.__name__, attrname,))
AttributeError: _RSAobj object has no '_randfunc' attribute
```

Has anyone an idea of why I get these errors suddenly?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea, but I also noticed that certain things changed in the api and the backend a couple of days ago.

Comment: Exactly, It basically broke all my workflow. For instance, it is no more possible to use the google-api-python-client combined with the Luigi orchestrator.

Comment: can you add more information about what broke with Luigi and the python client? I don't know what's happening, but I'd like to investigate more

Comment: What version of bq.py are you using and what version of oauth2client.py is getting loaded? While oauth2client.py revved a few days ago, prior to a couple of weeks ago bq client's setup.py specified oauth2client v 1.2. The bq.py packaging recently changed to bind to the oauth2client.py packaged within the bq sub-directory of the gcloud client installed with the Google Cloud SDK. If you are using custom binding to a different oauth2client version then you are running in an untested configuration.

Comment: My guess is that Luigi uses fork when you use it with many workers, and this enters in conflict with the new oauth2clientAPI. I use the last version of google-api-python-client (1.5.0) which comes with the last version of oauth2client (2.0.0 post1)